# Test execution of functions like from component did mount and component will receive props

Tags: react-native, jestjs, enzyme

I am trying to test a component where componentWillReceiveProps is calling Animated.parallel. I am unaware as to how go about testing the execution of this function using jest.

I have tried using spyOn, using the prototype

Comment: Have you tried using `const animatedMock = jest.mock("Animated")`? Make sure to run this _before_ importing the module you're testing. Also keep in mind that `componentWillReceiveProps` is deprecated and will be removed in future React versions. You should be using `componentDidMount` instead.

Comment: yes, did try that. the issue is that I am getting function not called. I feel that I am missing something as to how to actually test component chunks like these

Comment: What are you using to render the component? react-test-renderer, enzyme? I guess that the issue might be that `componentWillReceiveProps` simply didn't get called because of the way that your component has been instantiated.

Comment: I am using enzyme, pretty new to testing react components :P

Comment: Which enzyme method are you using: shallow, render or mount?

Comment: I am using shallow

Comment: Then it might be that `componentWillReceiveProps` doesn't get called. Check out [this page](https://gist.github.com/fokusferit/e4558d384e4e9cab95d04e5f35d4f913) which lists the differences between shallow, mount and render.